# Solr 3.1 facet range query

Tags: java, facet, faceted-search, solrj

Has anyone used the Solr 3.1 facet ranges for numerical values successfully? E.g. for document fields with the double or tdouble field type? (No analyzer)

My requests over SolrJ seem all to ignore the f.[fieldname].facet.range.start .end and .gap directives completely and I get ungrouped results.

(Regular facets worked correctly)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer is easy, there is a [bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-2523?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3acomment-tabpanel&focusedCommentId=13040439#comment-13040439) in solrj not supporting the ranged facets till currently version 3.2